# What is the convention for extension to be used in form actions of a spring mvc based application? ( .htm or .do)

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, dispatcher

Eg in form actions of struts based application, it is a common practice to use *.do or *.action as part of action.

Similar to this, what is the usual convention for form actions url in Spring MVC.
I had read somewhere that we use .html or htm. Is this correct?

eg if I have a form

```
<form action="registerUser.html">
   First Name: <input type="text"></br>
   Last Name: <input type="text">
</form>
```

Do we use .html as form action or something else.

If that is the case, then apart from configuring the incoming *.html requests to web.xml, how do we configure in Controllers. In the controller beans, will we map all incoming registerUser.html action to it's mapped method as follows:

```
@RequestMapping("registerUser.*")   // considering that there could be separate views later but registering logic will remain same     
public String registerUser(){

   // registering user

   return viewName;
}
```

OR  `@RequestMapping("registerUser.html")` could be used as well?

Answer (score 1):

You could use @RequestMapping in order to map the rest uri on a specific controller method. I'd recommend to use more specific mappings like: GetMapping, PostMapping, DeleteMapping and PutMapping.

Struts it's an old framework where you needed to manually define actions in some xml files. Please use spring-boot with Thymeleaf: https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/ , you'll create much faster 
and prettier web-apps with those frameworks.

As far as I know the name of the action could be just "**registerUser**"

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Will try to incorporate spring boot. But in meantime, just concerned if the app supports more than one framework like both spring and struts ( or something) then then maybe the front controller could differentiate and dispatch requests to the specific methods by seeing the extension of action. eg .do could be used for struts ( Or any other framework ) and .htm for spring based methods.

Answer (score 0):

As said in https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/ it is enough to implement the url associated to the corresponding view to be displayed (the returned greeting is the greeting.html file):

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that is fine while returning a view to the user when we are sure of the url, but while submitting a form, the action url in the form submission should have .html extension ( as a convention) ? I know its not necessary but just  in case we want to segregate the actions coming from different part - could be greeting page requested on a form submission from jsf, could be jsp page, or could be a different view.

Comment: In https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/ it is given the example of posting a form directly to the url without the .html. "(...) The th:action="@{/greeting}" expression directs the form to POST to the /greeting endpoint (...)"